# New to Pandas - Indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have loaded a .CSV value into pandas dataframe (with pd.read_csv) in Jupyter and trying to replace a NaN value with boolean value 'False'.I was able to identify the row where given nan value is by:

`dataframe[dataframe['columnname'].isnull()]`

However now i am getting trobules choosing the field in order to replace it with desired 'False' value. I recall that in numpy it was sufficient to name row and column number (exemplary `dataframe[3,5]` to extract desired location.

In current case, whenever I try to use row number i got an error 'invalid key'
Here are some methods that have failed:

`dataframe[dataframe['columnname'].isnull()].fillna('False')`  - fills in every NAN value in row with 'False', instead of filling in one cell 
`dataframe[rownumber, columnnumber]` - invalid key error
`dataframe[rownumber, 'ColumnName']` - throws invalid key as well

I am really sorry to bother you with such silly question, I would really appreciate any hint.

Comment: `dataframe[dataframe['columnname'].isnull(),'columnname'] = False` ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, tried that as well, but strangely gives me an info that object is not mutable and thus cannot be hashed. ( which is unusual, as when i run dataframe.info()  it clearly states that my object is dataframe, not a series).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read [Index and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html):

> dataframe[dataframe['columnname'].isnull()].fillna('False') - fills in every NAN value in row with 'False', instead of filling in one cell

```
df['columnname'] = df['columnname'].fillna(False)
```

Note: *in one cell*, do you mean in one column?

> dataframe[rownumber, columnnumber] - invalid key error

```
df.iloc[rownumber, columnnumber]
```

> dataframe[rownumber, 'ColumnName'] - throws invalid key as well

```
df.iloc[rownumber, df.columns.get_loc('ColumnName')]
```

Comment: Thank you for that advice, worked perfectly! I guess i panicked while seeing the error, worst reaction possible.